Angular test how to mock an imported const
I have an angular service being tested, which import a const from another file
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";

The environment.ts is like
export const environment = {
    ...window.mainConfig,
    production: false
};

window.mainConfig is an electron context bridge exposed variable. It is undefined in ng test context so I have to mock it.
I tried the following
import * as environment from '../environments/environment';

describe("...",()=>{
  beforeEach(() => {
    //...
    spyOnProperty(environment,"environment","get").and.returnValue({/* ... */});
    //...
  });
});

But this gives Error: <spyOnProperty> : environment is not declared configurable.
How do I mock this correctly?

Could you try Object.assign to override the internal properties with the new properties.
Object.assign(environment, {/* ... */});

If not you can run a loop across the properties and assign the values manually also.
const mockEnv = {/* ... */};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(mockEnv)) {
  environment[key] = value;
}

The most ideal solution is to configure in the angular.json, the environment replacement, for testing environment. This will be configured when you start testing.
"test": {
  ...
  "options": {
    ...
    "fileReplacements": [{
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.tst.ts"
    }],
    ...

Reference Answer

Thanks for bringing up the file replacement method.
